# KL divergence with perturbed random variable

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a random variable $X$ and an error term $\varepsilon$ which is independent on $X$. Both random variables are continuos and their support is all of $\mathbb R$. I want to compute the KL divergence between $X$ and $X + \varepsilon$, that is

$$D_{KL}(X \mid X + \varepsilon)$$.

Computing it directly is not easy, due to the presence of the density of $X + \varepsilon$ which is a convolution between the densities of $X$ and $\varepsilon$.

To simplify the expression, I thought of using the chain rule for KL divergence:

> **Chain rule for KL divergence** (*Theorem 2.5.3, Elements of Information Theory, Cover, Thomas 2006*) $$D_{KL}(P(x, y) \mid Q(x, y)) = D_{KL}(P(x)
>  \mid Q(x)) + D_{KL}(P(y \mid x) \mid Q(x \mid x))$$

where $D_{KL}(P(y \mid x)
 \mid Q(x \mid x))$ is the conditional relative entropy. On the book only the discrete version is considered; assuming that the continuous version is also valid, we have 
 $$D_{KL}(P(y \mid x) \mid Q(x \mid x)) = \int_\mathbb R p(x) \int_\mathbb R
 p(y\mid x) \log\frac{p(y\mid x)}{q(y \mid x)}dy dx$$

To use the chain rule, then, I need vectors; I don't have a vector in this case, but just a two scalar random variables. I can define two vectors as

$$\begin{pmatrix} X \\ X'\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} X \\ X+\varepsilon\end{pmatrix}$$

where $X'$ is an independent copy of $X$.

In this case then $P(x) = f_X(x)$, $P(x, y) = f_X(x) f_X(y)$ and $Q(x, y) = f_X(x)f_\varepsilon(y-x)$. Substituting in the formula above we get

$$D_{KL}(P(x,y)\mid Q(x,y)) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} f_X(x) f_X(y)\log\frac{f_X(y)}{f_\varepsilon(y-x)} dy\ dx$$

Now, assuming I can simplify this to my liking, how do I get back to what I originally wanted, that is

$$D_{KL}(X \mid X + \varepsilon) = D_{KL}(P(x) \mid Q(y))$$?

Thank you for any advice / reference :)

Comment: You can use the fact that $D(P(x)|Q(x)) \leq D(P(x,y)|Q(x,y))$ to get a bound?